# Save a plot in R without png dev.off()

Tags: r, slurm

I am running an R script in a batch mode on my university Linux HPC cluster. I am using a module with pre-installed R packages, so I don't think I can install anything.
R version is 4.0.3

I am trying to save the plots with

```
png("filename.png")
plot()
dev.off
```

But I got a "unable to start device png" error with "unable to open connection to X11 display ''" warning

I found some similar problems here, but neither of the suggested solutions worked. I tried

```
options(bitmapType='cairo')
png("plot.png", res=250, height=40, width=80)
plot()
dev.off()
```

and

```
png("plot.png", type='cairo', res=250, height=40, width=80)
plot()
dev.off()
```

still have the same error

Are there other ways to save a plot without using png() and dev.off()?

UPD: I checked capabilities() and both png and jpeg are FALSE there. Is there any way I can at least look at those plots? I do not have to save them

Comment: Check `capabilities()` for device png, its value should be `TRUE`.

Comment: it is FALSE for both png and jpeg. I guess I cannot change it. Are there any other ways to see the plot? I don't have to save it. I just need to look at it

Comment: To see it, don't call `png()` and `dev.off()`, just plot it. As for those devices not being installed, talk to your system admin, that's an abnormal (in the sense of rare) situation.